# Laravel Cache - Performance improvement not visible

Tags: laravel, caching

I'm currently working on the topic of Laravel Cache. In theory, an understandable topic. In practice, however, questions arise. Based on a tutorial, I wanted to put an object list (REST API: index) in the cache. I used the Cache::remember function for this. But I don't notice any performance improvement.

What I noticed is. Even without a cache function, the first request takes longer. The following are significantly shorter. The same with almost the same performance times is when I use the cache. From this I conclude that Laravel already uses the cache by default. Is that right?

*I use for the test:*

- Laravel 9,
- .env:
  DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
  CACHE_DRIVER=file
- OS: Linux
- API Testing Tool: Insomnia

#### Results:

**Without Cache:**

```php
public function index()
{
    return Article::all(); // 500 Articles
}
```

1. First call: 367ms
2. Second call: 248ms
3. Third call and > : ~214ms

**With Cache:**

```php
public function index()
{
    return Cache::remember('articles', 60, function() {
        return Article::all(); // 500 Articles
    });
}
```

1. First call: 351ms
2. Second call: 226ms
3. Third call and > : ~234ms

**Test request empty array without cache:**

```php
public function index()
{
    return [];
}
```

1. First call: 152ms
2. After that: ~142ms

With each call, two folders are created in the storage/cache/data folder, which in turn also indicates that Laravel uses the cache for requests from home.

**Question** Use Laravel by default Cache and it is possible to improve the performance more?

Comment: In my opinion and experience using Laravel cache for dynamic content is not a good idea.

Comment: @MartinAmu Thanks Martin for your answer. Can you explain why, please?

Comment: Hi Max Pattern, because as probably you know reading and writing new changes to the cache reduce server and website performance. Always first call has lower speed than further calls and checking the presence of new changes and r/w process is a time wasting cycle.